# Why debian installs linux headers in two different places?

Tags: kernel, dkms, linux-headers

Debian have two packages for headers one architecture dependent and another is not. They install headers in `/usr/src/$LINUX/common` and `/usr/src/$LINUX/$ARCH` and consequently two directories: build and source in `/lib/modules`. This causes a lot of problem in dkms.

Is there and good reason why it does that while vanilla one does not?

Comment: This case isn't debian causing any problems, i've never seen or  heard of this issue, I install the linux-headers package, and that's it Unclear what you are referring  to re vanilla, vanilla what? kernel package doesn't install headers, and vanilla kernel source isn't a package. You install the correct arch package, like linux-headers-5.10.0-5-amd64, and if it needs the common package, it wiil pull it in. If that then causes dkms issues, that's a bug with that module's dkms, not debian.

Comment: For example I have a module in which the build files looks for headers in `/lib/modules/$LINUX/build/include/linux/` but the file is in `/lib/modules/$LINUX/source/include/linux/` in debian. In generic kernel though it is in the build directory. Now I can change the upstream accordingly but shouldn't I consider only generic kernel?

Comment: You should look at  how all the other modules do it, no reason to reinvent the wheel. Clearly whatever module you are using didn't bother checking how to actually do this robustly so it works with packaged headers, so that's where you want to apply the fix. This isn't Debian's problem, it's not a packaging problem, it's just a problem with your specific module, which you seem reluctant to identify. In general when posting an issue, when you are asked for specifics and you fail to supply them, nobody will spend more time on your issue. At least  I won't.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too long for a comment, but it's not quite an answer.

You can help clarify unknowns by posting this:

```
inxi -Fxz
```

This will help show possible issues with your setup.

A few points:

1. dkms isn't a thing, it's a collection of  module and build scripts etc. You need to specify what module is failing, it's not dkms failing, that works fine with modules that work with the current Debian kernel. The fact that a specific dkms module is failing means you have to figure out why it's failing, not why standard Debian packaging is working correctly and as expected. Dkms is not failing, your module is failing, almost 100% certain.
2. It's not the job of Debian kernels to support any random module, so you have to be very specific about which module is failing. dkms has no generic issue with the standard Debian way of packaging headers, it works fine as long as the module and its dkms code is correct and supports the kernel.
3. You did not mention which branch of Debian you are  using, that matters, a lot. stable? next stable, aka 'buster', unstable?
4. You install the linux-headers package that corresponds to your architecture, then that pulls in the common package as a dependency. Common means common, that is, that 1 common package is the same across architectures, with occasional exceptions.

Example:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
...
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-686 - Header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-686
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-686-pae - Header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-686-pae
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-amd64 - Header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-cloud-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-common - Common header files for Linux 5.10.0-6
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-rt
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-rt-686-pae - Header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-rt-686-pae
linux-headers-5.10.0-6-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 5.10.0-6-rt-amd64
...
```

Note the exception, rt kernel has its own common files, but  otherwise that one common file is shared. Debian always does stuff like that, it's called good packaging. The fact that debian does good packaging is not a bug or issue, it's simply revealing a bug or issue in your dkms module.